# How to generalize '2021/11/27' in CASE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I'm a beginner.

I'm working on the following Query but it's not working well. Could someone help me?

This is the raw data.
[image]

I only want to take out of date such as '11/27/2021' from here. Not '100g' nor null.

Data type is STRING.

And my query is this.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN 
    date = 'm/%d/%Y' then PARSE_DATE("%Y/%m/%d", expiry_date) 
    Else null 
    end as date,
FROM
    my_database
```

I'm looking forward to your advise.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below few options

```
select safe.parse_date('%m/%d/%y', date) as date
from my_database
```

or

```
select 
 case 
   when regexp_contains(date, r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}') then parse_date('%m/%d/%y', date)
    else null
  end as date
from my_database
```

I recommend first option, but both return same output.

You can test with dummy data

```
with my_database as (
  select '11/27/21' as date union all 
  select '100m' union all
  select '' union all
  select null union all
  select '12/4/21' union all
  select '120g' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.Berlyant! It has worked as I expect. Thank you so much!

Comment: How can I accept your anser here sir? It's my first question here.